# How to write get text in grid.js using php tag

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to write get-text for language conversion with the help of php tag.
I try to use `gettext` php tag in grid.js but it's not working for language translation.

I have try this code for use `gettext` in generate_grid.js
Code:

```
word_hello = "<?php echo gettext("hello"); ?>"
alert(word_hello);
```

Using this code grid loading stopped so how I can use get text in jquery.

Using `gettext` flexigrid load without any error.

We have tried to another solution like call javascript function to header.php file like below.

```
word_hello = header_fcuntion('hello');
alert(word_hello);
```

In header.php we do like this.

```
  function header_fcuntion(txt){
      var new_txt = "<?php echo gettext('"+txt+"'); ?>";
      alert(new_txt);//Response in English Language hello
  }
```

But we try like put static hello that time it alert in converted language in header.php file.

```
  function header_fcuntion(txt){
      var new_txt = "<?php echo gettext('hello'); ?>";
      alert(new_txt);//Response in Convert Language hello
  }
```

So is there anything wrong to call function in php file?